# Acumatica GI Seeing Soft Deleted Data

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to make a Generic Inquiry(GI) able to see soft deleted data on Acumatica?  For example I'm working on a GI that looks at contact that's been deleted.  It is doing a Soft delete the column name is `[Contact.DeletedDatabaseRecord]`.  I'm working on Acumatica 2018 R2 verison number 18.206.0011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available for reports but not for generic inquiry.

A feature request exists for allowing selective filtering of the records marked as deleted in generic inquiry:
https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1728

It was created on 28 September 2018 and already has garnered five votes so there's a reasonable chance it gets implemented in future versions:

[image]

Comment: Now on 6 votes.. including mine. The workaround in the meantime is to create a standard inquiry screen with the customization editor (requires basic programming).